# How to enforce ARC Only in iOS Project

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I am going to develop iOS Project and its team members are geographically distributed with different time zones.

I want to somehow enforce ARC only !

Any helpful pointers?

Comment: Tell everyone you want them to use ARC.  Use code review and reject changes that don't conform to your requirements.

Comment: Isn't there anyway to show a compiler level or xcode level warning or errors ?

Comment: No, because any setting can be changed.

Comment: Yeah that's ok.But how to configure ?

Comment: So you want to know the build setting to use ARC?

Comment: Yes If anybody tries to go non-ARC the xcode should show some warning or compiler should throw error ?

Comment: Yes that's right.  Did you search the build settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Select Project
- Select Targets
- From the right panel, select Build Settings
- Search for Automatic Reference Counting
- Locate Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 - Language and Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting and select YES in all three sections.

Comment: Thanks for the step by step answer !